# Facebook Login : Not sending email in response after changed emails in facebook account. What to do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have implemented facebook login. It worked fine. After I changed email in my own facebook account, (I am using only mine during development), I am not getting email in the response anymore.
I tested the permissions with

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=${accessToken}&debug=all`

and its all fine, email access is granted. However I am only getting the id and name in response. After researching for a long time, I saw that it seems, that its a bug on facebook and when you change the emails, facebook graph api stops sending email in its response. Did anyone found a solution on what to do now in such a case?

Comment: First of all, did you _verify_ the new email, after you added it? Not verified addresses will not be returned. If you did that, then it might still be that you explicitly need to grant the app access to _this_ particular email address - Facebook often asks users the first time they grant the permission, which of their email addresses they want to grant access to. In that case, you might need to remove the granted permission first, and then ask for it again.

Comment: Yes,I did verify it. I removed my app from the apps on facebook too. I then logged out of fb, so I would be lead the the window where I am asked to sign in and grant permission (during loging on my own app). Im not sure if its important to note, but I did not verify immidiatly. However, I eventually did and then again did all the steps (removed app from facebook etc.). I was never asked which email to grant permission, but also have tried to deny first, then (after again removing app, logging out etc.) log in with facebook again and grant permission to email. Im still not getting the email.

Comment: It must be a Facebook bug. I've recently also changed the email and cannot log in into online store, as a user in prod.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that this is a bug on Facebook side. Recently, because of our requirements, I changed the email for my Facebook personal account and the moment I changed the email, that parameter was not pulled from Facebook API. Support ticket can be created to Facebook to see what is going on here and to investigate this bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/235289006341038/?post_id=235289013007704

Comment:  [Hey the link seems to be broken](https://ibb.co/SKtCnK6)